# How to update data in reff document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have schema like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Ticket = require("../ticket/model").Ticket;

const RatingSchema = new Schema({
    rating_id: {
        type: String,
        required: [false, "ID is required"]
    },
    rating: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        required: [false, "Name is required"]
    },
    feedback: {
        type: String,
        required: [false, "Detail is required"]
    },
    ticket_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: [false, "Priority is required"],
        ref : Ticket
    },
    created_by: {
        type: String,
        required: [false, "This field is required"]
    },
    created_date: {
        type: Date,
        required: [false, "This field is required"],
        default: Date.now()
    },
}, {collection: 'rating'});

const Rating = mongoose.model("Rating", RatingSchema);
module.exports = {Rating, RatingSchema};
```

and the service is like this:

```
EditRatingByParent: async function(id){
    try {
        const filter = { 'rating': {$ne: null} };
        const update = { 'ticket_id.rated': false };
        const rating = await Rating.find(filter)
        const ticket = await Rating.updateMany( {rating: {$ne: null}}, 
        {$set: {"ticket_id.rated": false}});
        if(ticket){
            return ticket;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to update reff object? i already try to reach the object with:

```
 {$set: {"ticket_id.rated": false}});
```

but the system still read that code as ticket_id field, the rated field is not reach. can someone help me to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you want to select all the rating documents matching specific filter criteria and update the ticket documents associated with them(via referencing), is that right?

Comment: Right, thats what i want. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to update ref object but not with single update query because data contained in two different collection.so you need to chain update statement and use return result.[refer this it may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349828/updating-reference-along-with-other-values-mongoose)